# Implementing multi touch and Pinch and zoom in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

how i can implement pinch to zoom and multi-touch features in windows phone 8. In my application i add 3 image containers in a grid and i need to perform the above mentioned operation on my image. Please any one help me to implement the functionality in my application. Thanks in advance.

Stez

Comment: Hi Stez am also trying to implement multi-touch in my app but it is not working. have you solve this problem ?

Comment: Yup it is working in ma environment without any issue, The main problem is with marketplace submission. I think you are facing the issue with missing reference. try to add all dependencies and re compile it will work.

Comment: which version you are using am using 0.5.0 and fallowed [this](http://www.galasoft.ch/touch/wp7/) it raise `the type MultiTouchBehavior' was not found`, and version 0.6.7 there is no installation option then how can i add .dll files in to my app

Comment: You can use the latest build from codeplex. here is the link http://multitouch.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/97043

Comment: no installation required for this? how can i add references to my app? can you please post and for this in detail :)

Comment: You please build the application in release mode and then take the dll's from release folder. And you can add that dll's to you project

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22832/discussion-between-stezpet-and-kartheek)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following library from codeplex:

https://multitouch.codeplex.com/

It performs the calculations required to scale / rotate an image when it is pinched.

Comment: Now they added new release for windows phone 8

Answer (score 1):

my solution which works for both WP7.5 and WP8:

XAML code

```
<StackPanel  x:Name="Scroll" Margin="0">
                    <Image  CacheMode="BitmapCache" Name="FrontCover"   Source="{Binding FullCover}"  >
                        <Image.RenderTransform>
                            <CompositeTransform x:Name="transform" ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1"  />
                        </Image.RenderTransform>
                        <toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
                            <toolkit:GestureListener   PinchDelta="OnPinchDelta" PinchStarted="OnPinchStarted" DragDelta="OnDragDelta"  />
                        </toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
                    </Image>
            </StackPanel>
```

```
 double initialScale;

    private void OnPinchStarted(object sender, PinchStartedGestureEventArgs e)
    {
        initialScale = transform.ScaleX;
    }

    private void OnPinchDelta(object sender, PinchGestureEventArgs e)
    {
        var curZoom = initialScale * e.DistanceRatio;
        if (curZoom >= 1 && curZoom <= 3)
        {
            transform.ScaleX = curZoom;
            transform.ScaleY = curZoom;

        }
    }

    private void OnDragDelta(object sender, DragDeltaGestureEventArgs e)
    {
        transform.CenterX = (transform.CenterX - e.HorizontalChange);
        transform.CenterY = (transform.CenterY - e.VerticalChange);

        if (transform.CenterX < 0)
            transform.CenterX = 0;
        else if ( transform.CenterX > Scroll.ActualWidth)
            transform.CenterX = Scroll.ActualWidth;
        else if (transform.CenterX > (FrontCover.Height * transform.ScaleX))
            transform.CenterX = FrontCover.Height * transform.ScaleX;

        if (transform.CenterY < 0)
            transform.CenterY = 0;
        else if (transform.CenterY > Scroll.ActualHeight)
            transform.CenterY = Scroll.ActualHeight;
        else if (transform.CenterY > (FrontCover.Height * transform.ScaleY))
            transform.CenterY = FrontCover.Height * transform.ScaleY;

    }
```

Think it should help others

Comment: GestureListener has been deprecated since Nov 2011 (http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2011/11/nov2011phonetoolkit/)

Comment: This is not the way to implement multiscale image.